# Splitting a text file into new files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file in the following format:

```
Model        1   
Atom….
Atom….
Atom….
ENDMDL
Model        2   
Atom….
Atom….
Atom….
ENDMDL
Model       n   
Atom….
Atom….
Atom….
ENDMDL
```

I need to split this  file into the files corresponding to each Model. The names of new files according to the Model’s number.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily done using a small *awk* script.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 
# Write sections of the input file to separate files
# Written by PM 2Ring 2016.06.14

BEGIN{outbase = "outfile"}

/^Model/{outname = outbase $2}

{print > outname}
```

`outbase` is the base file name. It gets the Model number appended to it, so for your sample file the output files `outfile1`, `outfile2`, etc will get created. With a minor change to the script you could set `outbase` from the command line, using awk's `-v` option.

The heart of this script is

```
/^Model/{outname = outbase $2}
```

It says: If the current line starts with "Model" append the contents of field #2 to the `outbase` string, assigning the result to `outname`.

By default, awk process a file line by line, splitting each line into fields using whitespace as the field separator.

```
{print > outname}
```

simply prints the current line to the file whose name is stored in `outname`.

---

This script is small enough to write the whole thing on the command line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{outbase = "outfile"}; /^Model/{outname = outbase $2}; {print > outname}' infile.txt
```

You can actually supply multiple input file arguments and they will be handled correctly, as long as you don't have duplicated Model numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go for this using `csplit`. This will work for a file called `file.txt`:

```
csplit -ksz file.txt '/^Model/' '{*}'
for xx in xx*
do
    newname=$(awk '{print $2; exit}' "$xx")
    test ! -f "$newname" && mv -f "$xx" "$newname"
done
```

The `csplit` splits `file.txt` into multiple parts based on the RE. Filenames are (by default) named as `xx` and a monotonically increasing numeric suffix. We look at each of these in turn and rename them to the model number found inside the file.

Any files matching `xx*` at the end of the loop contain duplicate model numbers (the renaming is performed on a *first come first served* basis).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

while read -r line                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    case $line in                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        Model*)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            f="${line//[[:space:]]/}"
            touch "$f"  # file name without white spces                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        ENDMDL)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            :                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            echo "$line" >> "$f"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    esac                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
done < "$1"
```

Something like this. You should run it providing models file as argument: `./script_name models.txt`

Note that as mentioned by @PM 2Ring this approach is slow specially if you have large files.

Comment: The filenames will be  `Model.............N`(dots are space).I'd assume OP would not want all that space in filenames.

Comment: Note that Bash `read` is rather slow. It obtains its input character by character, with a system call required for each character. It's really designed for interactive use, not text processing. Please see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/88378) for further details.